# Matrix exponential, computation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function

What is $e^A$, where$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 4 & 0 \end{pmatrix}?$$

Comment: Hint: use the power series expansion of $e^x$, then caclulate $A^0,A^1,A^2,A^3,A^4$ i bet you see a pattern

Comment: why the vote to close as 'off-topic'? This question admittedly does not show what the OP did to find an answer, but it certainly is _not_ off-topic.

Comment: It is off-topic due to lack of context. I downvoted and voted to close.

Comment: @user7530 with that reasoning you would have to close 75% of the questions posted here.

Comment: @Thomas That wouldn't be a bad thing, I'm afraid...

Comment: @Thomas welcome to MSE

Comment: @user7530 well if you want to start a crusade, why do you do that with a question which actually is meaningful? When I first encountered an exponential with a matrix as exponent I was completely lost. Did you lose your sense for the nonobvious over all your anger about the nonsense you see here?

Comment: @Thomas There is a 90% chance this question was copied from a homework and 10% chance this was copied from a test. Nobody writes down a matrix of random numbers and wonders, "what is the exponential of this *particular* matrix"? If the question had asked about exponentiation of general $2\times 2$ matrices, or even of general anti-diagonal matrices, or showed work, or gave *any* other indication this was a legitimate, non-homework question, I would have given it the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to find a basis in which the matrix has the form $B= D+N$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix, $N$ is nilpotents and $DN=ND$. Then, since $D$ and $N$ commute, 
$$\mathrm e^{B}=\mathrm e^{D}\mathrm e^{N}$$
The exponential of a diagonal matrix $D$ is the diagonal matrix with the exponentials of the diagonal elements of $D$ on the diagonal. The exponential of a nilpotent matrix can be computed with the series expansion of the exponential, which is really a finite sum for a nilpotent matrix.

Finally, let $P$ the change of basis matrix from the canonical basis to the new basis. We have $A=PBP^{-1}$, whence
$$\mathrm e^{A}=P\mathrm e^{B}P^{-1}.$$

Here $A$ is diagonalisable: one finds the eigenvalues are $\pm 2$ and a basis of eigenvectors is $\;\bigl\{(1,2),(1,-2)\bigr\}$, hence
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\2&-2\end{bmatrix},\quad P^{-1}=\frac14\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\2&-1\end{bmatrix}$$
and finally
$$\mathrm e^{A}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\2&-2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\mathrm e^2&0\\0&\mathrm e^{-2}\end{bmatrix}\cdot\frac14\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\2&-1\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}\cosh 2&\frac12\sinh 2\\2\sinh2&\cosh2\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

It is not so difficult to show  that if a $2\times 2$ matrix  $A$ has null trace than the exponential is:
$$
e^A=I \cos \theta +A \dfrac{\sin \theta}{\theta}
$$
where $\theta= \sqrt{\det(A)}$.

This comes from the definition of exponential as a series:
$$e^A=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{A^n}{n!}$$
 and from the fact that, for such a matrix, we have $A^2=-\det(A) I$

In your case, since $\det A <0$ use:

$$
\cos (i|\theta|)=\cosh |\theta| \qquad \dfrac{\sin (i|\theta|)}{i|\theta|}=\dfrac{\sinh |\theta|}{|\theta|} 
$$